# How do I import AngularJS 2 // import { routerTransition } from './router.module;

Tags: angular, import, transition

I am trying to apply page transitions with Angular 2, and the docs I read said I need to import

// import { routerTransition } from './router.module;

But I keep getting an error saying Cannot find module ''./router.module;'

What other imports do I need in oder to have access to the router module ?

Comment: James, I misread your question before answering. I apologize for any confusion. Your trying to import a class from a relative path, not your packages dir, so do you have that file? Also, what docs are you reading? It would help to see the context of what the docs are telling you.

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-animate-router-transitions-6de179e00204#.62100bb3z

Answer (score 1):

Try importing more specific module or component 
**import { routerTransition } from './router.animations'** 
instead of **'router.module'**.